# Is that the joint PMF $p(x,y) = p(y,x)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For the Joint Probability Mass Function (PMF)
If $X$ and $Y$ are two discrete random variables.
Is that the joint PMF $p(x,y) = p(X=x,Y=y) = p(Y=y, X=x) = p(y,x)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah you're asking about symmetry. well no (i guess...depending on definition/notational/conventional issues).

For $p(x,y):=p(X=x,Y=y)$, we have

$p(y,x):=p(X=y,Y=x)$

This is because the capital $X$ and $Y$ don't change!

Comment: but I see that $p(x,y) = p(X=x,Y=y) = p((X=x \text{ and } Y=y))$. Also, $X=x$ and $Y=y$ is same as saying $Y=y$ and $X=x$. So, $p((X=x \text{ and } Y=y)) = p((Y=y \text{ and } X=x)) = p(Y=y,X=x)=p(y,x)$

Comment: @xxxxxx i believe your error is the last part  $p(Y=y, X=x) = p(y,x)$. actually $p(X=y, Y=x) = p(y,x)$

Comment: @xxxxxx just imagine $p(a,b):=p(X=a,Y=b)$ so the 1st argument is the value for $X$ and the 2nd argument is the value for $Y$

Comment: okay, I think I get it, $p(X=x,Y=y)= p(Y=y, X=x)$ but $p(y,x) = p(X=y,Y=x) \neq p(Y=y,X=x)$ so $p(x,y)\neq p(y,x)$

Comment: indeed. indeed.